# Generate footer page number for each p/@outputclass="kingbreak"

Tags: xslt-2.0, dita

**Input Dita file**

If any topic has **p/@outputclass="kingbreak"**, we want to create footer page number with horizontal, I tried with xsl:number/ but it is picking disorder page number, Please help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dit xmlns:dita-ot="http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net/ns/201007/dita-ot">
    <topic>
        <title/>
        <body>
            <p>content here</p>
            <p>content here <ph/>content here</p>
            <p outputclass="kingbreak"/>
        </body>
    </topic>
    <topic>
        <title>SELF title</title>
        <body>
            <p>body content</p>
        </body>
        <topic>
            <title>content here</title>
            <body>
                <p>
                    <b>content here</b>
                </p>
            </body>
            <topic>
                <title>content here</title>
                <body>
                    <section>
                        <p>contenet here</p>
                        <p outputclass="kingbreak"/>
                    </section>
                </body>
            </topic>
            <topic>
                <title>content here</title>
                <body>
                    <section>
                        <p>content here</p>
                        <p outputclass="kingbreak"/>
                    </section>
                </body>
            </topic>
            <topic>
                <title>title content here</title>
                <body>
                    <p>content here</p>
                    <p outputclass="kingbreak"/>
                </body>
            </topic>
            <topic>
                <title>content here</title>
                <body>
                    <section>
                        <p>content here</p>
                        <p outputclass="kingbreak"/>
                    </section>
                </body>
            </topic>
    </topic>
    </topic>
</dit>
```

**XSLT**
I tried with below xslt, it is generating random page number

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p[contains(@outputclass, 'kingbreak')]">
            <xsl:number/>
            <hr style="border-top:1.5pt solid #000000;" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:stylesheet/>
```

Please help on this, thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us the exact output structure and the exact page numbers and positions in the output structure where you want to generate them. Just throwing in `xsl:number` certainly can't do the right thing magically, but it has various attribute like `count` and `from` and `level` that can do some "magic".

Comment: With nested `topic`s perhaps `<xsl:number count="topic" level="multiple"/>` makes some sense. But you really need to show the output structure and number structure you want to generate.

Comment: See below my current output, it's picking only page number 2

Comment: <topic>
                <title>content here</title>
                <body>
                    <section>
                        <p>contenet here</p>
                        <div>2</div><hr style="border-top:1.5pt solid #000000;"/>
                    </section>
                </body>
            </topic>            <topic><title>content here</title>
                <body>
                    <section><p>content here</p><div>2</div><hr style="border-top:1.5pt solid #000000;"/></section>
                </body>
            </topic>

Comment: It's very long output but I am giving only occurrences code. In <div>2</div> is our page number, later I will do style right now I want correct page number, Please help me, I unable to get.

Comment: Number structure should be like 1,2,3,4,......

Answer (score 1):

Try whether `<xsl:number level="any" count="p[contains(@outputclass, 'kingbreak')]"/>` gives you the wanted sequence of numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin, It's working fine